# mySQL field type question

Tags: mysql

I have db table cell that stores 5-digit zip code, however when the zip starts with 0 it is dropped and only 4 digits are stored. Currently the column type is set to INT(5), but clearly this is not working.

What type shall I use instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Try using a CHAR(5) data type if it's always going to 5 digits long

Answer (score 2):

Try using int(5) zero fill. Then you get the speed of an int but the zero at the front. I recently had this issue and solved it this way.

Answer (score 1):

`CHAR(5) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin`